# Swift iOS: How to refactor a lot of conditions for if statement?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, refactoring

I have a string that is retrieved from a keychain, and I transform the string to a dictionary. Then, I check the values of the dictionary to see wether or not it is nil or empty.

```
   override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    var dictionary = [String : Any]()

    if let jsonData = A0SimpleKeychain().string(forKey:"Dictionary")?.data(using: .utf8), let jsonDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String : Any] {
        dictionary = jsonDictionary
    }

    if let key = dictionary["key"] as? String, !apiKey.isEmpty, let shouldSync = context as? Bool  {
      // Do Stuff
    } else {
     // Do Stuff
    }
   }
```

However, I feel like there is a better way to accomplish this specifically the if statement checks. There might be more dictionary values I have to retrieve in the future. If anyone has tips or suggestions, I will deeply appreciate it.

Edit: I am trying my best to not use the bang operator. That is why I am using a lot of conditions.

Comment: Use `guard` instead https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard is your friend...

```
guard
    let jsonData = A0SimpleKeychain().string(forKey: "Dictionary")?.data(using: .utf8),
    let dictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String : Any],
    let key = dictionary["key"] as? String,
    !apiKey.isEmpty,
    let shouldSync = context as? Bool 
else {
    // Failed. Do stuff.
}

// Conditions all passed. Continue...
```

The guard statement will fail when a 'test' fails.